# Innacurate Y Coordinates in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm testing getting the mouse position in a `canvas` in Javascript.

I decided to try something: I wanted to draw a rectangle at the position the mouse clicked on, but when I click anywhere on my canvas, the rectangle does draw at the `X` position of the cursor, but not on the `Y`.

I then went to see what the problem was, so I made it so that the coordinates of the mouse on the `canvas` were visible, and I got interesting results.

[image]

In short: it's telling my cursor's `Y` position was `0`, even though it wasn't at the top of the `canvas`:

```
ctx.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
  var status = document.getElementById('status');
  status.innerHTML = mouseX + ' | ' + mouseY;
});

ctx.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var mouseX = event.clientX - ctx.canvas.offsetLeft;
  var mouseY = event.clientY - ctx.canvas.offsetTop;
  item.drawItem(mouseX, mouseY);
});
```

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: Can you replicate the issue inside a codepen or jsbin?

Comment: Interestingly, in jsfiddle, it works perfectly fine. https://jsfiddle.net/Static_Cloud/0awfz27s/10/ . Maybe the content above might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left` instead of `ctx.canvas.offsetLeft` and `canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top` instead of `ctx.canvas.offsetTop`. See if this works?